# Calculation going to infinity

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate the gamma function of a number and it is going to infinity. When I use maple (for instance) it returns the correct answer (2.57e1133 (yes, it's huge)). I tried to use DECIMAL but 0 success. Is there a solution? Thanks in advance.

the code

```
import scipy as sp                             
from scipy.special import gamma
from decimal import Decimal
from scipy import special


def teste(k):
    Bk2 = Decimal(gamma((1/(2*k))+(3/4)))
    return Bk2

print(teste(0.001))
```

Result

Infinity

Comment: it appears that gamma does to inf quite often: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.gamma.html

Comment: You should expect overflow for some values. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, but not in this particular case. It is a big number, but it's not infinity. And that changes everything for my research purposes. I did some research and apparently is a limitation of python. I also tried to use different gamma functions (m.gamma etc) and nothing changed.

Comment: The maximum float in Python is about 1E308.

Comment: OH, I see... Anyway, thank you Stefan and @Paul. I appreciate your help, as always.

Answer (score 0):

I used `gammaln` to prevent overflow, then I cast the result to Decimal. Lastly, I use the exponential function to recover the intended result.

```py
import scipy as sp                             
from scipy.special import gammaln
from decimal import Decimal
from scipy import special
from numpy import exp

def teste(k):
    Bk2 = exp(Decimal(gammaln((1/(2*k))+(3/4))))
    return Bk2

print(teste(0.001))
```

Comment: Thank you! It is a smart solution but the ideal conditions for my research would be by calculating gamma functions directly.